# Elasticsearch skip null values

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

there are empty fields in the document I created.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(uri)).DefaultIndex("person");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

for example;

```
 var newPerson = new Person() 
 {
  newPerson.Name = "Jack",
  newPerson.Age = 30,
  newPerson.Image = "";
 }

 var savePerson = client.Create(newPerson , i => i.Index("person"));
```

I don't want to save the "Image" field when saving.

Can I ignore this field or skip it while saving?

Comment: Would projection be acceptable?

Comment: @DCAggie it wouldn't be a good solution for me because I have too many fields in my class and each result returned may have different fields null.

Comment: While defining the connections settings, you can create a custome serializer which could ignore NULLS and use that settings in elstic client.

Comment: @SharathNS i use JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include but the null fields are still being saved.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html

Comment: I guess if you dont want to include Null values, the setting should be NullValueHandling.Ignore

Comment: @SharathNS It still saves empty fields when I use Ignore.

Comment: Check this https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm You might have to include a default value for your properties and then ignore the default values too. Else you could set the image to null if tit is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property:

```
newPerson.Image = null;
```

and it won't be saved to elastisearch

Comment: Welcome to SO! When paste code here, format it using the code tag {} for code (CTRL-K) like I did in the Edit